# rails - any good example on submitting a form via json in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I want to add some ajax functionality to my rails app with json.
what I want to do is just to create a form taking data entry.
After submitting the form, I want to grab a response in json formatt
to update the screen without re-rendering the form.

as I looked through the website, I didn't find one yet that explains the concept
comprehensively.

could you kindly point me out any source online or any books that could teach me step-by-step to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/creating-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

It'd be more helpful if you stated what, specifically, you're having issues with--adding `:remote => true` is the bulk of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty simple concept:

1. Using your form helper (assuming Rails 3) set the `:remote => true` option.
2. Make sure you have the appropriate jQuery UJS / Rails.js file on your layout. It will automatically latch onto the `data-remote` attribute that the helper generates on the form and submit that form via AJAX.
3. Modify your controller action to return JSON (see below).
4. Use the provided callbacks/hooks in JS to handle the response (see below).

Example:

```
# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
  if @foo.save 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @foo }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => :new }
      format.json { render :json => { :errors => @foo.errors } }
    end
  end
end

# app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'form[data-remote]', (xhr, data, status) ->
  # do something with `data`, which is a JS object from your JSON response
  # console.log data
```